# Changing the reference pointer is changing the original pointer address

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

S has been allocated dynamic memory.S->name has been assigned part of the dynamic memory. Though I am not performing any operation on s->name,s->name is changing in BEFORE and AFTER prints

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct meta_data
{
    int roll_no;
    int section;
    int age;
}meta_data;
typedef struct student
{
    meta_data mt_data;
    char* name;
}student;
int main(void)
{
    student *s = malloc(sizeof(meta_data) + 10);
    s->name = (char *)s + sizeof(meta_data);
    printf("sizeof(meta_data) = %d \n", sizeof(meta_data));
    printf("-----BEFORE-----\n");
    printf("s               = %d \n", s);
    printf("&(s->meta_data) = %d \n", &(s->mt_data));
    printf("s->name         = %d \n", s->name);
    char* ptr = s->name;
    printf("ptr = %d \n", ptr);
    ptr += 3;
    printf("ptr+3 = %d \n", ptr);
    memcpy(ptr, "sri", 3);
    printf("-----AFTER-----\n");   
    printf("s               = %d \n", s);
    printf("&(s->meta_data) = %d \n", &(s->mt_data));
    printf("s->name         = %d \n", s->name);
    return (0);
}
```

```
Output :
sizeof(meta_data) = 12
-----BEFORE-----
s               = 22638608
&(s->meta_data) = 22638608
s->name         = 22638620
ptr = 22638620
ptr+3 = 22638623
-----AFTER-----
s               = 22638608
&(s->meta_data) = 22638608
s->name         = 22636914
```

Comment: Don't use `%d` to print the value of `sizeof(...)`, use `%zu`. Don't use `%d` to print the values of pointers, use `%p` and cast the pointer to `(void*)`.

Comment: Also: This `student *s = malloc(sizeof(meta_data) + 10);` is not safe. The size of a `student` is not `sizeof(meta_data) + 10`. It could be less, but it could also be more. Why not `malloc(sizeof *s)` to get the proper size?

Comment: Assume that length of the name is always less than 10 bytes

I want to avoid a separate memory allocation to name
& want to store it continuously as part of student.

I have kind of simulated the problem here.

Comment: `name` is a `char*` - it's usually 4 or 8 bytes. Never 10 - but the `struct` will probably have padding too so you can't calculate the size the way you do. Compare `sizeof(student)` with `sizeof(meta_data) + 10`

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to make `name` a flexible array? If so, define it like this: `char name[];` and remove `s->name = (char *)s + sizeof(meta_data);`. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/d1vz4sa63) (with all the above issues fixed)

Comment: Don´t overcomplicate things. `typedef struct student { meta_data mt_data; char name[10]; } student;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not `printf`. The problem is your call to `memcpy`, which, unless you are well-seasoned in C programming, I would avoid for now. `memcpy` takes two addresses, destination and source, and copies the bytes found in source into destination. Your call provides such as an address. The source address is the statically-allocated "sri" char pointer which the compiler automatically generates.

So, removing the call to `memcpy` will make the program do as you expected.